# A query both for objects with a certain attribute set to nil and last one not set to nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

`Category` has many `Post`.

I want a collection (of the AssociationRelation class) with:

all posts that has the attribute `published_at` set to `nil`

TOGETHER WITH

the post with the most recent "published_at" date

Separately the two queries look like the following:
    `.where("published_at is NULL")`
    `.order(published_at: :desc).limit(1)`

**But how could I have a collection that's the result of both?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `partition`

```
recent, rest = Post.order('published_at DESC').partition{ |e| e[:published_at] != nil }
recent_one = Array.new << recent.first
@posts = recent_one + rest
```

So, in `@posts` the first post will be the most recently published post and the rest will be with `published_at` `nil`

Comment: The second line is giving me: `undefined method \`+' for #<Post:0x00000102ebd0b8>`

Comment: But your `+` method gave me the idea to simply add the results of my two posted queries to eachother, and it seems to work! :)

Comment: Yes, see my edites answer, that error was coming because `recent.first` was not an array, so converting that to array and then adding will resolve the problem and that too in a single query :)